# How to trigger a 2nd script to run simultaneously without affecting the Main script and with the possibility of adding multiple additional scripts?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

Note:
I am updating my original post on 12/22/23 to better explain what is it that I am trying to achieve. Perhaps, this will make it easier to provide some suggestions.

I am trying to build a notification bot!
This bot will run continuously, checking every 3 min if a given item has restocked. If it has, it will send an email to a group of recipients to notify them about the restock. What I now want to do, is to split said group between a preferred group (which will be notified as soon as the bot finds the item back in stock) and a second group which will receive the same email but 10 min later (delayed notification).

The rest of my post still stands. Script 2 will wait 10 min and then send an email (which would take 2-5 seconds) and then exit. I do not need Script 2's result to run my main script. So I really do not need to keep track of Script 2 once it begins waiting.

As per some of the initial comments. At no point should there be more than 3 instances of Script 2 running simultaneously. Given that Script 2 waits for 10 min and then takes 3-5 seconds to complete its instructions, even if the Main Script finds the item in stock every 3 minutes, by the 4th time it finds the item (12 min since the first time), the first instance of Script 2 should have already ended. I hope that makes sense.

After reading about threading I came up with this super simple example of what I believe would be the structure of my scrip. Can someone tell me if this is wrong? Will I run out of resources if I run this script endlessly?

```
import threading
import time
import random

def delayed_email():
    time.sleep(10)
    print ("Delayed Email has been sent")

def immediate_email():
    print ("Immediate Email has been sent")

while True:
    number = random.randint(0,3)
    print (number)
    if number == 1: 
        immediate_email()
        print ("Starting Script 2")
        threading.Thread(target=delayed_email).start()
    time.sleep(3)
```

----Original Post -----

I need help figuring out, conceptually, how to write a script that would do the following:

Main Script:
Run continuously, checking every 3 minutes if a certain condition has been met.
If condition has been met, then run some code and immediately trigger Script 2.
After this, go back to sleeping for 3 minutes. Rinse and repeat either if the condition is met or not.

Script 2:
If triggered by Main Script, if would sleep for 10 min and then run some code. Once finished, it is done. Main Script does not depend on this script. But Script 2 will only run if triggered by Main Script.

Questions about this:
I do not think I can use async, in this scenario right? I believe this is more for concurrency, either multithread or multiprocessor, I just do not know which one and why. Or perhaps I'm wrong and I need to organize my logic some other way.

Also, Script 2 should be it's own entity that will live and die as soon as it finishes its code. This means that, for example:

1. Main script runs and condition is met.
2. Main script runs code and then triggers Script 2
3. Main scrpit goes back to waiting for 3 minutes. While this is happening, Script 2 is sleeping for 10 minutes
4. Main script's condition is met again 3 minutes later, hence it runs its code and immediately triggers a 2nd entity of Script 2 (since the first entity is still sleeping waiting for the initial 10 min to elapse)

In the example above, there are now two instances of Script 2 running simultaneously. One with 7 min left to sleep, while the new one is just starting to sleep 10 min, all while Main Script is going back to waiting for another 3 min.

With all this in mind, would multithread work or better to use multiprocessor? If none of this would work, what other options do I have to organize the logic to trigger Script 2 parallelly.

thanks

Comment: Given your requirements the number of threads (if using threading, for example) can potentially increase indefinitely since they can be potentially started every 3 minutes but take 10 minutes at least to execute. And there is generally a limit to the number of threads that can be created. Why not share what your actual problem is rather than asking for help with an approach that may not be workable?

Comment: added an answer with limits

Answer (score 0):

Threading is probably the most obvious way to do it

but you could use https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html or
async https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon

here is some code that does the wait in seconds instead of minutes and has a random condition as the criteria to start a thread.

```py
import time
import random
from threading import Thread

def bgtask():
    print("SLEEP 10 START")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("SLEEP 10 END")

def main():
    while True:
        print("SLEEP 3 START")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("SLEEP 3 END")
        if random.random() > 0.5: # Just a random condition
            print("STARTED TASK")
            t = Thread(target=bgtask)
            t.start()
```

For the updated question where thread limits are needed there are out of the box options for threads and processes https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit can be used (The same code can also be used with processpool with limits)

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import random
import time

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(10) # Limit of 10 threads

def bgtask():
    print("SLEEP 10 START")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("SLEEP 10 END")

def main():
    while True:
        print("SLEEP 3 START")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("SLEEP 3 END")
        if random.random() > 0.5: # Just a random condition
            pool.submit(bgtask)
```

However you can still end up scheduling an unlimited number of tasks - one good workaround may be to make the main thread wait if you have too many tasks scheduled which can be done with a semaphore like this.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import Semaphore
import random
import time

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(10) # a random limit of 10
sem = Semaphore(20) # Number of tasks that can be scheduled to complete. Should be > pool size

def bgtask():
    print("SLEEP 10 START")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("SLEEP 10 END")
    sem.release()

def main():
    while True:
        print("SLEEP 3 START")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("SLEEP 3 END")
        if random.random() > 0.5: # Just a random condition
            sem.acquire()
            pool.submit(bgtask)

main()
```

For async tasks you could just create a semaphore and it should be fine https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore and await sem.aquire() it before starting the and

```py
import asyncio
import random

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10) # Limit of 10 tasks

async def bgtask():
    print("SLEEP 10 START")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("SLEEP 10 END")
    sem.release()

async def main():
    while True:
        print("SLEEP 3 START")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print("SLEEP 3 END")
        if random.random() > 0.5: # Just a random condition
            await sem.acquire()
            asyncio.create_task(bgtask())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Why consider the number of tasks that have already completed (which, by the way, could be determined just by incrementing a counter instead of appending a task instance to `completed_tasks` and checking its length)? After 10 threads have completed you will never start another thread again. That can't be correct. Of course, given the OP's requirements the number of threads (if using threading) can potentially increase indefinitely since they can be potentially started every 3 minutes but take 10 minutes at least to execute. There is a limit to the number of threads that can be created.

Comment: Also, you seem to be appending to `completed_tasks` threads that are still alive.

Comment: Hey @Booboo 
Thanks for responding. You are incorrect with your assumption that infinitely number of threads can be created. Remember that Script 2 waits 10 min, runs some code and then ends. All this while main script is checking every 3. So even if main scripts' condition is met every 3 min. Only Max 4 Script 2 would be running at any given time. By min 12 the first script 2 should have ended. Script 2 only sends an email so it takes 1-2 seconds to complete. Does that change your answer? Thanks

Comment: @Carlos_OL You are correct about there not being more than 4 threads running. But I believe the OP's code is incorrect for the other two reasons I mentioned: (1) Every time a thread completes `len(completed_tasks)` grows by 1 and therefore `len(completed_tasks) + len(running_tasks) < 10` will be False eventually and the main thread will terminate and (2) The check should be `if not running_tasks[i].is_alive(): completed_tasks.append(running_tasks.pop(i))` if you wish to keep track of completed tasks (but why?). Or am I still missing something?

Comment: yeah that code was botched and I removed it, and replaced it with a random condition.

Comment: Thank you @Booboo, So I wonder if the goal of my script might change things.
The main script is waiting 3 min and check if condition is met. If met, then it sends a notification via email to a list of recipients. It then triggers Script 2 that will wait 10min and then send another email to a 2nd list of recipients. That is truly the goal of my whole script. I want to somehow separate these two lists, where one gets immediate notifications, while the second is delayed by 10 min. Knowing now what I want to achieve... does it change anything?
Thanks again for taking the time t help me figure it

Comment: Perhaps at an even higher level. I wonder how people manage to create notification bots that can split the same message, into multiple, where one gets an immediate notification once condiiton is met, while the other group has to wait X minutes for the same message. All while never stopping the main script that checks for the condition.

Comment: @Carlos_OL See my posted answer.

Comment: @Booboo, Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. Let me review your suggestion and try to understand it. Code seems a bit more complicated than my super barebones example above, so I need to make sure I understand the differences and the benefits it brings.
thanks again

Comment: @arrmansa, Thank you too for helping me. Like my post above. I need to review and understand your suggestion. This is somewhat new to me, so I want to make sure I grasp the benefits of what you guys recommended and compare them to my super simple example.
Thanks

Comment: @Carlos_OL Concentrate more on the `asyncio` example since it is simpler (and perhaps preferable). The threading example has extra code (e.g. using a callback function with the `apply_async` method solely to prove that the size of the pool only needs to be 4 if sending emails is more-or-less instantaneous).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at module subprocess. if you have your scripts in seperate .py files, you might be able to achieve your goal by using subprocess.popen, but you have to compile your script1 and script2 to .exe first i think.

Comment: popen can run py files, no need for exe

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Per the suggestion made by armansa, because we cannot make any assumptions on the time needed for the tasks to send emails, we need to put a limit on the number of submitted tasks. For this a semaphore is used.

You can use either a multithreading  but better yet would be `asyncio` coroutines (see below) since the the maximum number of threads that are allowed to be created may be too limiting.

If using multithreading I would use a fairly large size pool to handle situations where the condition required to send emails is met frequently within a short period of time requiring and the time it takes to send emails is sufficiently large that a large number of tasks need to be running concurrently. **Because there is a maximum number of threads that can be created I believe that using `asyncio` coroutines is the better way to go.**

In the multithreading version below I have overridden the definition of `MINUTE` from 60 (seconds) to 1 (second) so that the demo runs faster but the real code should just use `MINUTE = 60`. I have also for demo purposes added counters to keep track of the number of tasks that have been submitted and the number of tasks completed to compute the number of tasks currently running.

### Multithreading Version

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from threading import Semaphore
import time

MINUTE = 60 # One minute is 60 seconds
# For demo purposes we will wait 10 seconds instead
# of 10 minutes:
MINUTE = 1

start = time.time()

def check_condition() -> bool:
    """Check if some condition exists and return True
    if it does else False."""
    ...
    return True

def send_email_to_recipents_1() -> bool:
    """Send an email to the first list of recipients."""

    print('Sending email to the 1st recipient list at', round(time.time() - start))
    time.sleep(5)  # Assume it takes this task a while to run
    ...

def send_email_to_recipents_2() -> bool:
    """Send an email to the second list of recipients
    after sleeping for 10 minutes."""

    time.sleep(10 * MINUTE)
    print('    Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at', round(time.time() - start))
    time.sleep(5)  # Assume it takes this task a while to run
    ...

def main() -> bool:
    """Performs the OP's requirements."""

    MAX_TASKS = 30

    thread_pool = ThreadPool(MAX_TASKS)
    tasks_submitted = 0
    tasks_completed = 0

    semaphore = Semaphore(MAX_TASKS)

    def task_completion_callback(result: None) -> None:
        nonlocal tasks_completed

        semaphore.release()
        tasks_completed += 1

    # Provide a way (user hits Ctrl-C) to terminate the program:
    try:
        while True:
            if check_condition():
                semaphore.acquire()
                thread_pool.apply_async(send_email_to_recipents_1, callback=task_completion_callback)
                tasks_submitted += 1
                print('#tasks executing =', tasks_submitted - tasks_completed)
                semaphore.acquire()
                thread_pool.apply_async(send_email_to_recipents_2, callback=task_completion_callback)
                tasks_submitted += 1
                print('#tasks executing =', tasks_submitted - tasks_completed)
            time.sleep(3 * MINUTE) # sleep for 10 minutes
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass # We now terminate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
#tasks executing = 1
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 0
#tasks executing = 2
#tasks executing = 3
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 3
#tasks executing = 4
#tasks executing = 4
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 6
#tasks executing = 5
#tasks executing = 5
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 9
#tasks executing = 6
    Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at 10
#tasks executing = 6
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 12
#tasks executing = 7
    Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at 13
#tasks executing = 6
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 15
#tasks executing = 7
    Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at 16
#tasks executing = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 18
#tasks executing = 7
    Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at 19
#tasks executing = 7
#tasks executing = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 21
    Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at 22
#tasks executing = 6
#tasks executing = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 24
    Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at 25
#tasks executing = 6
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 27
#tasks executing = 7
    Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at 28
#tasks executing = 6
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at 30
#tasks executing = 7
...
```

### `asyncio` Version

```py
import asyncio
import time

MINUTE = 60 # One minute is 60 seconds
# For demo purposes we will wait 10 seconds instead
# of 10 minutes:
MINUTE = 1

TASK_TIME_REQUIRED = 5

number_of_tasks_running = 0
start = time.time()

def check_condition() -> bool:
    """Check if some condition exists and return True
    if it does else False."""
    ...
    return True

async def send_email_to_recipents_1(semaphore) -> bool:
    """Send an email to the first list of recipients."""

    global number_of_tasks_running

    print(f'Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = {round(time.time() - start)}')
    ...
    await asyncio.sleep(TASK_TIME_REQUIRED)
    number_of_tasks_running -= 1
    semaphore.release()

async def send_email_to_recipents_2(semaphore) -> bool:
    """Send an email to the second list of recipients
    after sleeping for 10 minutes."""

    global number_of_tasks_running

    await asyncio.sleep(10 * MINUTE)
    print(f'   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = {round(time.time() - start)}')
    ...
    await asyncio.sleep(TASK_TIME_REQUIRED)
    number_of_tasks_running -= 1
    semaphore.release()

async def main_2() -> bool:
    """Performs the OP's requirements."""

    global number_of_tasks_running

    # Coroutines tasks are inexpensive, we can afford to start many of them.
    # The larger the number, the less chance that an email will be delayed.
    # It is also assumed that under actual conditions that emails will not be needed
    # to be sent every 3 seconds in which case the number of running tasks will not exceed
    # some maximum amount and that the number of running tasks will decrease so that we
    # never need to have more than MAX_TASKS tasks running concurrently:
    MAX_TASKS = 100
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(MAX_TASKS)

    while True:
        if check_condition():
            await semaphore.acquire()
            number_of_tasks_running += 1
            asyncio.create_task(send_email_to_recipents_1(semaphore))
            print('Number of tasks running =', number_of_tasks_running)
            await semaphore.acquire()
            number_of_tasks_running += 1
            asyncio.create_task(send_email_to_recipents_2(semaphore))
            print('Number of tasks running =', number_of_tasks_running)
        await asyncio.sleep(3 * MINUTE) # sleep for 10 minutes

def main() -> bool:
    try:
        asyncio.run(main_2())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Number of tasks running = 1
Number of tasks running = 2
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 0
Number of tasks running = 3
Number of tasks running = 4
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 3
Number of tasks running = 4
Number of tasks running = 5
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 6
Number of tasks running = 5
Number of tasks running = 6
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 9
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 10
Number of tasks running = 6
Number of tasks running = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 12
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 13
Number of tasks running = 6
Number of tasks running = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 15
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 16
Number of tasks running = 6
Number of tasks running = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 18
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 19
Number of tasks running = 6
Number of tasks running = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 21
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 22
Number of tasks running = 6
Number of tasks running = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 24
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 25
Number of tasks running = 7
Number of tasks running = 8
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 27
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 28
Number of tasks running = 6
Number of tasks running = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 30
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 31
Number of tasks running = 6
Number of tasks running = 7
Sending email to the 1st recipient list at time = 33
   Sending email to the 2nd recipient list at time = 34
...
```

Comment: There's no limit on the max number of tasks in your asyncio code.

Comment: @armansa I am not sure what the point you are making is. But in the "worst case" scenario if the condition for sending emails is always met, then two tasks will be created every 3 seconds (the second task will sleep for 10 seconds before sending its emails). If the work performed by these tasks take longer than 3 seconds, then the number of tasks running will increase indefinitely and I am not sure there is any solution that can be done that follows precisely the OP's specifications. (more...).

Comment: @armansa If, however, these emails always bear the same content, one can check if uncompleted tasks are already running and if so, not start up a new tasks.

Comment: My point was that the worst case scenario of unlimited tasks should be accounted for using a semaphore in case of threading / async / multiprocessing and pausing the main thread until the total number of tasks reduces.